# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory in preprocessing my js fiels

Tags: javascript, node.js, fatal-error

i am trying to preprocess my js files for each platform and beautify it using my js-preprocess.js .i am able to process upto 153 files.if the number of files increase,the console is showing the following error! 
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
Please help me to resolve this!
here is my one code snippet for the main job!

```
fs.readdir(inputdir,function(err,files) {
     console.time('PreProcessingJStime')
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        if (file.indexOf(".js") != -1) {
            console.log('PreProcessing JS File : '+file);
            fs.writeFile(outputdir+"/"+file,beautify.js_beautify(preprocess(fs.readFileSync(inputdir+"/"+file,'utf-8'),defines).join('\n'),{preserve_newlines:false}));
        }
    },this);
    console.timeEnd('PreProcessingJStime')
})
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Firstly, is this the bit of code that eats up all the memory? (The place where it actually crashes isn't necessarily the main memory consumer.) I have no idea what `beautify` and `preprocess` are - do they allow you to stream the files in some way instead of loading a whole file into memory at once?

Comment: im actually assuming that this is eating up the memory coz here is the place where inputdir for all unprocessed js files are passed,processed and beautified. 

Preprocessing -- ex:
 //#ifdef ios
 //#define ios_Platform
 //endif
 //#ifdef android
 //#define android_platform
 //endif
 //#ifdef ios_Platform
 function(){
  xxxIOS
 }
 //#endif
 //#ifdef android_Platform
 function(){
  yyyy
 }
 //#endif
 
 
 After preprocessing for ios  gives
 function(){
  xxxIOS
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `fs.writeFile`, which is asynchronous. This means you're writing to all files at the same time, and all the data needed for this is buffered in memory. If you change it to `fs.writeFileSync`, then it finishes with one file before moving on to the next one, and all the data concerning previous files becomes garbage, so the garbage collector will get it when it needs to.

Comment: Yeah David,I could figure it out now.
increading the space by --max-old-space-size=5500 is solving the issue for now.
But as memory getting dumped while reading folder async and writing async,i want to reduce this memory usage.
i am getting errors when i changed it to writefileSync as file is not found and stuff!
Could you please help me in that api for reading and writing synchronously

Comment: It should work if you just replace `writeFile` with `writeFileSync`. Any errors from `writeFileSync` probably would have happened with `writeFile` if it hadn't run out of memory first. Could you give more details about the new error messages? As for File Not Found errors: Is it possible that something else is deleting files? And do you have read access to the files? And could it be that some of the "files" are actually directories?

Comment: sry it was utf-8 encoding missed previously.i modified the code like this::::
var files = fs.readdirSync(inputdir,files);
files.forEach(function(file){
console.log(file);
 if(file.indexOf(".js") != -1){
    console.log('Preprocessing JS File : '+file);
    var content =beautify.js_beautify(preprocess(fs.readFileSync(inputdir+"/"+file,'utf-8'),defines).join('\n'),{preserve_newlines:false});
    fs.writeFileSync(outputdir+"/"+file,content,'utf-8');
   }
   
});::::::::::::::::::still those memory is piled up.help me in clearing the memory before going to other file

Comment: 5500MB for max-old-space-size seems a lot, but some people say it has a max value of 1700MB or so. And bear in mind it doesn't just store the input file contents in memory, but also the output of `preprocess` and `beautify`. Possibly all at the same time, depending on how clever the garbage collector is about scoping of (implicit) variables. For all I know, a 500MB file or less could be enough to crash it. And could it be that the operating system is refusing to allocate more memory to nodejs, even though you've told nodejs it's allowed to? (Are other processes eating memmory?)

Comment: actually we have few other building jobs while this is running.as we started running code through the terminal,we came to know that this alone is eating up more memory.and moreover the js files are 210 in number that is around 949 MB.So is there any way to approach this reading and writing synchronously sort of idea? thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd thought the total size of files shouldn't matter with `writeFileSync`, since it should finish one before it starts another. But: http://www.daveeddy.com/2013/03/26/synchronous-file-io-in-nodejs/ . So try using `fs.fsyncSync` or `setTimeout` to give kernel time to flush its buffer. Failing that: What if you run it without the other jobs? How big is biggest file? Very roughly, how much memory do you think it takes to generate the output file? I think you said it always fails on same file - is that file particularly memory-intensive? It's possible `beautify` or `preprocess` has a memory leak.