# NPM Search: Running out of memory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

On ubuntu 14.10 (3.13.0-76-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux), when I do:

```
sudo npm search yeoman-generator
```

I get the following error:

```
npm WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

NPM Version is 3.7.1

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL ERROR: CALL\_AND\_RETRY\_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory in preprocessing my js fiels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154423/fatal-error-call-and-retry-2-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory-in-prepr)

Comment: @Waki I have not written any code yet as mentioned in your linked Question

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of node and npm?

Comment: Yes, I have node installed. And I am using npm. Previously I installed yeoman and hence now want to install yeoman-generator, but ended up with this error message. Although I could simply install it, I wanted to do npm search but then it fails.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While not a solution, per say, I typically do my searches on http://npmjs.org

Even when it works, npm search is epically slow due to the size of the index. I would recommend avoiding it unless you have no available browser.

See the canonical NPM search doesn't work issue:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6016

Answer (score 7):

According to npm's bug tracker, this has been fixed in npm@4.0.0. (see [thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12619)).

Searching works fine for me after [upgrading npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12619#issuecomment-261689262):

> npm install npm@latest -g

(you might need to su/sudo on your system)

Comment: Upgrading npm (right now at 4.1.2) resolves the issue. This should be the preferred answer at this point.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be downloading https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all/
and copying the file to

> ~/.npm/registry.npmjs.org/-/all/.cache.json

This is what happens in the first step. It looks like "downloading" via Node.js is not the best idea.

Comment: That link now 404s

Comment: The link works if you remove the trailing slash [https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all](https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all) ... but take note of the accepted answer - it is a BIG index!

Comment: I just tried this, and npm search *still* runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I stumpled upon this problem. For my Linux machine i wrote a little bash function to search the website. Its located here for others to use, if they want: http://pastebin.com/U27X7pqT

Its no "4ever"-Solution and a little hakish, but it works currently.

Edit: Output looks like this:

```
$ npmsearch react
react  (v15.3.2) - React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces.
react-emoji-react  (v0.3.0) - a clone of slack emoji reactions in react
react-accordion  (v0.1.0) - React Accordion
react-phux  (v0.0.1) - React + Phux
react-toolbar  (v0.1.1) - React Toolbar
react-pure.css  (v0.1.7) - React Pure.CSS
```