# Is there a npm module search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, package

would there be a module search command ?

Something like `dnf search node` on my fedora or `apt-get` on other linuxes ?

I am not interested in third-party programs, just native tools

Comment: Did you go to the NPM website? `npm search package-to-search-for`

Comment: theres also just package search functionality on the npm web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm search
```

Search the registry for packages matching the search terms.

If a term starts with /, then it's interpreted as a regular expression. A trailing / will be ignored in this case. (Note that many regular expression characters must be escaped or quoted in most shells.)

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search

Answer (score 0):

I validated the right answer, but just because before asking my question I was aware of `npm search` but I kept having a `Javascript FATAL ERROR: JavaScript heap out of memory`. Here I post a link to a workaround for anyone who would experience the same trouble.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307484/773595